# Why would a subclass of a subclass of zope.interface.Interface not inherit its parents names?

Tags: python, zope.interface

Example:

```
>>> from zope.interface import Interface, Attribute
>>> class IA(Interface):
...   foo = Attribute("foo")
... 
>>> IA.names()
['foo']
>>> class IB(IA):
...   bar = Attribute("bar")
... 
>>> IB.names()
['bar']
```

How can I have IB.names() return the attributes defined in IA as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the [`zope.interface.interfaces` module](http://apidoc.zope.org/++apidoc++/Code/zope/interface/interfaces/index.html) you'll find that the `Interface` class has a [`IInterface` interface definition](http://apidoc.zope.org/++apidoc++/Interface/zope.interface.interfaces.IInterface/index.html)! It documents the `names` method as follows:

```
def names(all=False):
    """Get the interface attribute names

    Return a sequence of the names of the attributes, including
    methods, included in the interface definition.

    Normally, only directly defined attributes are included. If
    a true positional or keyword argument is given, then
    attributes defined by base classes will be included.
    """
```

To thus expand on your example:

```
>>> from zope.interface import Interface, Attribute
>>> class IA(Interface):
...     foo = Attribute("foo")
... 
>>> IA.names()
['foo']
>>> class IB(IA):
...     bar = Attribute("bar")
... 
>>> IB.names()
['bar']
>>> IB.names(all=True)
['foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, zope.interface on docs.zope.org is gone and I didn't think to check the method signature until after I had posted the question.

Answer (score 2):

Got it:

```
IB.names(all=True)
```

I guess I should check method signatures more in the future.